# AngularJS - Dynamic routing with UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, url-routing, angular-ui-router

So I have my fully functional static router within my awesome angularjs-powered single page application and now I get the task to make certain routes dynamic.

Say until now I had the following parametric paths:

- `^/user/:userName`
- `^/product/:productName`
- `^/category/:categoryName`

Now they would all need to respond to the path `^/:slug`, which would make a call to some backend API to get the type of resource that corresponds to that slug and finally forward the request to a specific `controller` with its specific `resolve`, `templateUrl`, `abstract` and `data`.

Any thoughts?

---

(**EDIT**: I guess the same functionality would be possible with route mirrors (aka transparent forwards) where *internally* another route than the requested is triggered, even though the route change is not publicly visible. But I'm still ignorant towards whether any of this is possible in angular or ui-router... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It ain't pretty but it works nicely.

Besides renaming my existing routes above to `^/:username` (alias 'profile'), `^/:productName` (alias 'products') and `^/:categoryName` (alias 'category'), I created a new generic route `/:slug` with its controller `ResolverController`. The latter must be declared first in the `$stateProvider`.

`ResolverController` is the following function:

```
function ($state, $stateParams, resource) {
  switch (resource) {
  case 'user':
    $state.go('profile', {'username': $stateParams.slug});
    break;
  case 'product':
    $state.go('products', {'productName': $stateParams.slug});
    break;
  case 'category':
    $state.go('category', {'categoryName': $stateParams.slug});
    break;
  default:
    // 404
    break;
  }
}
```

You might wonder about the third parameter `resource`. It's returned by the resolve of this state and holds the information about the type of the resource of the requested slug.